# Cannot convert value to AST with Apollo Client & GraphQL .NET

Tags: .net, graphql, apollo-client

I am facing a weird issue when I use Apollo Client in React to call a .NET GraphQL backend.

For some unknown reason I am getting the following error on my String types:

```
Cannot convert value to AST
```

My backend is working fine if I post queries and mutations using *fetch* or *axios* but this error only happens with Apollo.

I had to change my **Variables** type to be **Inputs** instead of **JObject** because of Apollo and the error started to happen.

Here is my new GraphQL request class:

```
using GraphQL;

namespace xyz.com
{
    public class GraphQLQuery
    {
        public string OperationName { get; set; }
        public string NamedQuery { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public Inputs Variables { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It used to be this though:

```
public class GraphQLQuery
        {
            public string OperationName { get; set; }
            public string NamedQuery { get; set; }
            public string Query { get; set; }
            public JObject Variables { get; set; }
        }
```

If I use JObject I get a null object in my post method with an Apollo call.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I figured out how to fix this issue after a few hours.

This is what I did.

I changed my API method parameter to the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] System.Text.Json.JsonElement rawQuery)
```

Then I added the following line to deserialize the rawQuery value to a GraphQL request object:

```
var graphQLQuery = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphQLQuery>(rawQuery.ToString());
```

And now the code works perfectly.